# Where is LayerZero's core component?

Tags: solidity, blockchain-interoperation, interoperability

I have read a whitepaper about LayerZero's whitepaper and decided to dig deeper. For that I checked [layer zero](https://github.com/LayerZero-Labs/LayerZero.git) repository. According to the white paper, core functionality of a LayerZero endpoint is encapsulated in 3 modules, **communication**, **validation** and **network**. However I could not understand which part of the project stands for those 3 modules' functionality. And it was written that the **relayer service** is currently provided by layer zero labs. I wanted to know how the relayer service is orgranized but could not find layer zero's relayer service repository on my own. Can anybody help me to identify **key components** and **relayer service**'s mechanism?

Comment: I suggest you ask from LayerZero developers directly. It's unlikely people outside the small core contributor team of LayerZero can help you.